# three.js editor will not execute position change script

Tags: javascript, three.js

Disclaimer: I am utilizing the three.js editor (https://threejs.org/editor/) as an ide to create an animated 3d scene with 6 objects and 6 directional lights.  The scene itself will export and display without any animation/position changes. 
When I attempted to add this script below to edit the xy positions of the objects the scene will not display when I press play.

```js
var box = this.getObjectByName ('box');
var filledTube =this.getObjectByName('filledTube');
var ball =this.getObjectByName('ball');
var dice =this.getObjectByName('dice');
var tube =this.getObjectByName('tube');
var knot=this.getObjectByName('knot');
var blue1=this.getObjectByName('blue');
var blue2=this.getObjectByName('blue2');
var red1=this.getObjectByName('red');
var red2=this.getObjectByName('red2');
var green1=this.getObjectByName('green');
var green2=this.getObjectByName('green2');

function update( event ) {
var time = (event.time*.01);
 box.position.x=-time;
 box.position.y=-time;
 filledTube.position.x=-time;
 filledTube.position.y=-time;
 ball.position.x=-time;
 ball.position.y=-time;
 dice.position.x=-time;
 dice.position.y=-time;
 tube.position.x=-time;
 tube.position.y=-time;
 knot.position.x=-time;
 knot.position.y=-time;
 
 blue1.position.x=+time;
 blue1.position.y=+time;
 blue2.position.x=+time;
 blue2.position.y=+time;
 red1.position.x=+time;
 red1.position.y=+time;
 red2.position.x=+time;
 red2.position.y=+time;
 green1.position.x=+time;
 green1.position.y=+time;
 green2.position.x=+time;
 green2.position.y=+time;
}
```

I cannot find any information on google on the editor so here I am... any help or direction to documentation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try event.delta instead of event.time in the update function. My guess is that all objects are moving to fast.

So in update function:

```
var time = (event.delta*.01);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The script works and probably "kicks" everything far away, out of the view.
The reason is that the event.time values are very big, even if they are divided.

To see those objects, and move them in the scene try this:

```
var speed = 0.02;
box.position.x += speed; // adds 0.02 to the current box x position value
box.position.y -= speed; // subtracts 0.02 to the current box y position value
```

A nice tool, the browser console, can help you track values (for example: event.time) and solve problems.

For example: Add the following line inside the update function and see for yourself the huge time values.

```
console.log(event.time); // outputs time values
```

You can learn more for console [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)